# Blazor wasm - debugging - can't view values of any variables

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor wasm project, that I have upgraded to .NET5, I can set breakpoints in components and the breakpoints work fine however I can't view the values of any variables, either by hovering over them or  in the "Locals" window or Immediate Window.

I created a new Blazor wasm hosted web app and changed the Counter component to use code behind (the same way im doing it in my other app), and that works ok, it shows the values of variables.

I've compared csproj files and Program.cs and can't see any reason why showing variable values when debugging would work in 1 project but not the other.

Answer (score 2):

I have now figured it out.
This project was an upgrade from .net core 3.1 to .net5, there was a line in the server project's csproj file that when i changed it from

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="3.2.1" />`

to

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="5.0.0" />`

I can now see variable values when debugging.